# Your connection was interrupted. ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED when parse with Selenium

Tags: selenium, parsing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, connection

I wrote a parser in `selenium`, which clicks to different links and parses data. But from time to time I get an error

> Your connection was interrupted. ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED

Perhaps this error is not related to `selenium`.

But, if I wait a little (about 1 second), then the connection appears again and I can continue to parse.

What way is there to solve this problem programmatically? Maybe in this case, somehow, I can reload the page until the connection appears again?

Comment: I imagine that the error message is coming from the browser you're driving with Selenium, so it might not be a bad idea to mention which browser that is.

Comment: @rici Chrome (webdriver)

Comment: all is latest versions

Answer (score 1):

For me using a mac system and chrome for a daily basis, I encounter this problem now and then and finally found it might be helpful to solve this problem by just turning off the virtual machines or dock containers whichever can adjust your network configuration.

Maybe not fit for your case but it could be a hint. You can turn them off for a while if you have them running.